# Manhwa in which the main character is reborn in a book she'd read as a silver-haired maid who dies at the hands of an empress jealous of her beauty

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm interested in reading this manhwa, but the poster never mentions the title anywhere. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of searching a screen grab, it looks to be [*The Villainess's Bestie*](https://tapas.io/series/the-villainesss-bestie/info)

[image: Front cover of The Villainess's Bestie]

> 5-year-old palace maid Charlie knows that in this world, she will be murdered out of jealousy by the villainous empress at a young age. Her only sources of hope are her plan to escape the palace as soon as possible, and her best friend Rose, a fellow maid who's like a big sister to her. However, when Charlie discovers that the kind-hearted Rose is actually the empress in disguise, her plans come crashing down around her. Can Charlie stay close enough to the empress to make it out alive?